# Procedure for producing a total order on infinite set

Tags: logic, axiom-of-choice

Suppose we want to prove that every **infinite** set, $X$, can be totally ordered. A probably faulty procedure I thought of was the following: by the Axiom of Choice we know that there exists a surjection $f:X\to\mathbb{N}$. If the preimage $f^{-1}(n)$ contains one element we say $f^{-1}(n)<x\in f^{-1}(m)$ if $n<m$. If $f^{-1}(n)$ is finite we can order this preimage set by using the bijection with $\{1,2,\dots,|f^{-1}(n)|\}$. If $f^{-1}(n)$ is infinite we apply this procedure again using the surjection $f':f^{-1}(n)\to\mathbb{N}$. It might be that this does not stop in finite steps. So should it stop, for constructing a total order? If so, why?

Comment: You are right, this may not terminate in fintely many stesp. For example, with $X=\Bbb R$ and $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ (this maps to $\Bbb Z$, instead of $\Bbb N$, but that doesn't matter), the preimages $f^{-1}(n)$ are all again of continuum cardinality, i.e, no progress at all has been made. -- I suggest , you use the Axiom of Choice's cousin, Zorn's Lemma, to find a maximal partial order and show that it is total

Comment: What do you precisely mean with 'no progress'?

Comment: Noah means that $f^{-1}(n)$ has the same cardinality as $X = \Bbb{R}$ for every $n$ so that your proposed construction doesn't simplify the problem in any way. I don't think there is any way of choosing, $f$, $f'$, $f''$ and so on that will make your construction terminate in finitely many steps if $X$ is uncountable. Have you found an example where the construction does terminate?

Comment: Any finite termination on an infinite set would imply that the set is countable, so for uncountable sets it is impossible to terminate finitely, right?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen does the lexicographic order on $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ also not make 'progress'?